# input field conversion from js to jsp input field

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have an input field in js page likewise i need to create in jsp page, please guide me

attached code of js is https://www.paste.org/124319

for the another js file
https://www.paste.org/124321

```
    $("input[value='Table']").attr("onclick","javascript:showWaitImage('" +
 chartId + "'); setHCFormField('frmChart_" + chartId + "', 'view_type' 
,'T'); displayHCChart('" + chartId + "');");
```

I have created a jsp button
which works similar

```
<button chartId="200121"  domain="MI"  chartname = "bplist" buttonName= 

    "Table" id = "bodyContent"
                                                                data-keypage="chartModal" class="btn btn-primary pull-right values">
                                                                <span class="sr-only">BP List</span>BP List</button>
```

but buttonName= "Table" is not going in query param
Convert this js script to jsp input fiels

Comment: Use an HTML input field and an onclick handler? What’s the specific issue?

Comment: setHCFormField what to do with this ?

Comment: Nothing; it’s JS and has nothing to do with the server side.

Comment: Changing the DOM using client-side JS doesn't go anywhere near JSP so you can't use JSP tags and attributes there.

Comment: @Quentin how can i achieve this in jsp ?

Comment: The JS is looking for an input with the value “Table”.  It’s not clear what **supposed** to be happening but if you’re missing a query parameter then you’re either missing a form input field or it’s named incorrectly.